# Sharing axes only in some subplots of Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have 3 subplots created with `plot_ly` (one for men, one for women and one for the gap). Since the `gap` is the subtraction of `m-w`, the ranges of `m` and `w` are far from the ranges of gap.

**Is it possible to share axes only for `m` and `w`, and keep the axes for `gap` free?**

`shareY=TRUE` and `shareX=TRUE` would make all three axes equal, but I only need to share two of them. Also, I don't want to plot the gap in a separate call of `plot_ly` because I need the legend to be linked to all the three plots (so I can hide/show markers).

Sample data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
set.seed(197)
a <- tibble(
  pais = rep(c("ARGENTINA", "BOLIVIA", "BRASIL", "CHILE", "COLOMBIA"),each = 2),
  sexo = rep(c("m", "w"), 5),
  ea1 = rnorm(n=10, mean = 50, sd = 1),
  ea2 = rnorm(n=10, mean = 40, sd = 1))
a <- a %>% 
  group_by(pais) %>%
  summarise(sexo = "gap",
            across(ea1:ea2, ~ -diff(.x))) %>%
  bind_rows(a) %>% ungroup()
```

Plot:

```
a %>% group_by(sexo) %>%
  group_map(~ plot_ly(data=., x = ~ea1, y = ~ea2,
                      color = ~pais, type = "scatter", mode="markers",
                      showlegend = (.y == "m"),
                      legendgroup = ~pais), keep = TRUE) %>%
  subplot(nrows = 1, shareX = TRUE, shareY=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `group_map` for the subplots to share a legend. If you use the same data to create the plots and legend, Plotly is going to gravitate towards keeping a single legend regardless. If you wanted to keep the `gaps` free, your best bet is nested subplots. For that, you'll need to pull them out of the `group_map`.

First, I'm going to create three separate plots: `plt1`, `plt2`, and `plt3`. Then I'm going to nest their subplots. I'm not entirely sure what you mean about having three plots but wanting the m/f to have a separate space. If they truly share x and y, there is only one plot.

```
# create a plot for each unique sexo
map(1:length(unique(a$sexo)),
    function(h) {
      df1 <- filter(a, sexo == unique(a$sexo)[h])
      p <- plot_ly(df1, x = ~ea1, y = ~ea2, color = ~pais,
                   type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
                   showlegend = (unique(a$sexo)[h] == "m"),
                   legendgroup = ~pais)
      assign(paste0("plt", h), p, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    })
```

Nest them.

```
subplot(plt1, subplot(plt2, plt3, shareY = T), widths = c(.33, .66))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! It works great out of Shiny. However, my code is within a `renderPlotly({ })` so it turns the object plt1 is not found when I run the app. I guess it might be related to `envir = .GlobalEnv`?

Comment: I'm not having any issues with the code as is with Shiny. However, there are a ton of ways you could have your app set up. Are you creating the plots outside of the `server`? (I tested it with the data outside of `ui` and `server`, with the `map` and `subplot` calls in `renderPlotly({})`.